# Mocked version of extension function not called

Tags: kotlin, mockk

In the following, I mock extension function `addOne()`, but `verify` fails:

```
data class Foo (
    val a: Int
)

class ClassInTest {
    fun doStuff(foo: Foo) {
        println(foo.addOne())
    }
}

object ObjectClass {
    fun Foo.addOne(): Int {
        return this.a + 1
    }
}

class TestClass {
    @Test
    fun `test`() {
        with(mockk<ObjectClass>()) {
            val foo = Foo(a = 5)

            every { foo.addOne() } returns 23

            val testClass = ClassInTest()

            testClass.doStuff(foo) // This calls addOne()

            verify { foo.addOne() }
        }
    }
}
```

The mocked version `addOne` is not called.

If I create a mock version of `Foo`, the mocked version of `addOne` is called, but calling `doStuff()` results in 24 getting printed.

```
    @Test
    fun `test 2`() {
        val testClass = ClassInTest()
        val foo = mockk<Foo>()

        every { foo.addOne() } returns 23

        testClass.doStuff(foo) // Should print 23, not 24

        verify { foo.addOne() } // Successful
    }
```